# ¿Cómo hago para que un ícono no se muestre en php?

Tags: php, html5

Resulta que tengo definida la variable "order" en la que cargo un dato específico con un ícono al lado en html, la cual debe mostrar en el navegador, pero cuando deseo no agregar ningun valor a la varible o en el campo, si lo dejo vacío me muestra el ícono siendo que no debería mostrarse tampoco si es que decido no colocar datos en esa variable o campo.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                            <?php } if ( '' !== $business_data['order'] ) { ?><i class="fa fa-ship fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo esc_html( $business_data['order'] ); ?>
                        </div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato hay en `$business_data['order']`? Quizá pueda servirte `!empty($business_data['order'])` en lugar de comparación estricta contra cadena no-vacía.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema se debe a que estas pintando html sin usar la logica de php ya que lo cerraste anteriormente. Proba con el siguiente código.

```
<?php } 
if ( '' !== $business_data['order'] ) 
{ 
echo '<i class="fa fa-ship fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
}
?>
```

Por otra parte, con el operador de comparación !== estas preguntando si es de diferente tipo, y a su vez si no es igual.
Yo usaría != ya que no podemos asegurarnos de que el tipo sea el mismo, podría ser null, empty, '', etc.